# React.js unit test click event with Enzyme and Sinon

Tags: reactjs, onclick, sinon, enzyme

I'm trying to attach a spy to a click event on my react component. I am using `Enzyme with Mocha` and `Chai` but I'm having trouble getting the following test to pass:

```
it('Handles a Click Event', () => {
    let rootId = Bigtree['rootId'];
    const spy = sinon.spy();


    const render = shallow(<EnvH tree={smalltree.objects} 
    node={smalltree.objects[rootId]} root={rootId}/>);


    render.find('.toggler').simulate('click');

    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
});
```

Here is the component I am testing:

```
class EnvH extends React.Component {
return (
  <div className='top' key={Math.random()}>
    <div className={'tableRow row'} id={node.id} style={rowStyle} key={Math.random()}>
      <div style={nodeStyle} className={'root EnvHColumn ' + classNames(classObject)} key={Math.random()}>
        //Here is the actual Click Item in question
        <span className={'toggler'} onClick={this.toggleCollapseState.bind(this)}>{node.type} - {node.name}</span>
      </div>
      <ColumnContent columnType={'description'} nodeInfo={node.description} />
      <ColumnContent columnType={'createdOn'} nodeInfo={node.createdAt} />
      <ColumnContent columnType={'updatedOn'} nodeInfo={node.updatedAt} />
    </div>
    <div className={'Children'} style={childrenStyle} key={Math.random()}>
      {childNodes}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Here is the function that gets called when the span gets clicked:

```
  toggleCollapseState() {
     this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed});
  };
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this one. I should also mention that the test is not passing stating that it is expecting true but found false.

Comment: Please let me know if you need additional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is not passing because the `spy` function is not given to the `span.toggler` element, so it's never called by it.
To make the test pass you should instead write

`sinon.spy(EnvH.prototype, 'toggleCollapseState')`

and then

`expect(EnvH.prototype.toggleCollapseState.calledOnce).to.be.true`

Comment: Wow Thanks for the response. I've been so busy and Have not had a chance to check back on this. I will try this later today and Mark as correct if it works.